# How can I efficiently find all almost perfect numbers from 1 to n in C

Tags: c, numbers

I have been trying to find all [almost perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number) between 1 and n in C.

I know that the the definition of an almost perfect number is that the sum of a number's divisors should equal that number -1.

My approach is that I iterate from 1 to that number, calculate the sum of its divisors, and then check if the sum is equal to that number -1 like in my code below.

```
int checkAlmoastPerfect(int n)
{
    int divisors = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {

        if (n % i == 0)
            divisors += i;
    }

    if (divisors == 2 * n - 1)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

And it seems to work but it is rather slow. Checking 100 or 1000 numbers is not too bad, but if we go to something in the range of millions it takes a very long time, so after looking around I see that there is an approach that I do not need to check all numbers from 1 up to that number, but only up to the square root of that number.

So I change the for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=sqrt(n); i++) { ... }
```

and the check to this

```
if (divisors == n - 1)
        return 1;
```

But it doesn't work at all now: if I check the numbers from 1 to 100 I get that only 1, 2 and 4 are almost perfect numbers, which is wrong as there are a few more.

What have I done wrong here, and how can I make my original approach more efficient?

Comment: What are "almost perfect numbers"?

Comment: consider using `i * i <= n` as loop condition

Comment: your original loop is executed for `i == n` thus `if (n % n == 0) divisors += n;`. As result `divisors >= n` which is never equal to `n-1`.

Comment: If you go only to sqrt(n), you must add 2 divisors, one for i and one for n/i

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 are indeed almost perfect numbers. More info at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPerfectNumber.html . Why do you think your code is wrong?

Comment: @tstanisl `i * i <= n` is prone to overflow when `n` is near `INT_MAX`.  Could use  `i  <= n/i`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, overflow is probably a lesser problem. One can always use `unsigned` to mitigate the problem even further. `n/i` would be far slower than `i*i` however, it will likely be merged with following `n % i` into a single assembly instruction. So `i <= n / i` is probably more proffered for this specific application

Comment: @tstanisl True, good compilers do merge the two.  Could use `div()` if concerned.  IAC, slow or fast, it is stiil the same O() with `i <= n/i` correct for large `n`.  I'd make a prime list if `i <= n/i` was not fast enough,  That would reduce O().

Comment: what is the maximal `n`?

Comment: To find the sum of the divisors of a number, it is efficient to factor the number and multiply geometric series formed from prime factors. For example, consider 72 = 2^3•3^2. Form the series of the powers of 2 in it (1+2+4+8 = 15) and of the powers of 3 (1+3+9 = 13). Then multiply them (15•13 = 195). To see this is the sum of the divisors of 72, observe that (1+2+4+8)•(1+3+9) = 1•1+2*1+4*1+8•1 + 1•3+2•2+4•3+8•3 + 1•9+2•9+4•9+8•9, so it contains every combination of the prime powers. This includes 72 itself as a divisor, so subtract that to get the total of the proper divisors, 195−72 = 123.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `n` is not super huge you could try calculate the sum of divisors for each number in range `1` to `n` at the same time. Rather that check if each number is divisible by `d` to increment its sum of divisors one can simply add `d` to the sum of divisors for number that are divisible by `d`. That leads to simple and efficient algorithm as below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 10000;

int main() {
  int *sum = calloc(n + 1, sizeof *sum);
  for (int d = 1; d <= n; ++d)
    for (int p = 0; p <= n; p += d)
      sum[p] += d;

  // find number which sum of divisors (including itself) is 2n - 1
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    if (sum[i] == i + i - 1)
       printf("%d\n", i);

  free(sum);
}
```

The program produces:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
```

Powers of 2 are returned what is consistent with the current knowledge on "almost perfect numbers".

The complexity is:

```
n + n/2 + n/3 + .. = O(n * log(n))
```

No modulo nor division is needed though the algorithm is not very cache friendly.

Comment: This idea is kind of cool but... 1) it can only handle `n` upto ~65000 (assuming 32 bit int) and 2) it uses a lot of memory. The first problem can be solved by doing 64 bit calculations but that will only make the second problem worse. But still kind of cool.

Comment: @4386427, 1) `int` is fine, `unsigned` would totally suffice. The maximal sum of divisor in range 1..1e8 is 487710720 for 99459360. It looks that the limit is growing slowly like `n * O(log n)`. 2) The memory might be issue for large `n`. There are a few ways to battle that at the cost of making the code more complicated. What is the maximal `n`?

Comment: Well, `sum[0]` will be`1+2+3+...+n` so that will be integer overflow (i.e. UB) at about ~65000 but... `sum[0]` can simply be skipped as it won't be a solution anyway. In other words... with a minor code that seems easy to solve.

Comment: @4386427, yes, `sum[0]` is a garbage anyway because it is infinity. It will overflow everything ;). Btw feel free to use fixed width types like `uint32_t` or `int32_t`

Answer (score 2):

> it doesn't work at all now

The summation needs work too.

```
    //if (n % i == 0)
    //  divisors += i;

    if (n % i == 0) {
      divisors += i;
      if (i*i < n) divisors += n/i;
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i < n/i; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        divisors += i + n/i;
}
// look for perfect square
if (i == n/i) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        divisors += i;
}
```

`i <=sqrt(n);` is dodgy to use FP here given `sqrt()` may only be weak and *almost* right.  Best to use integer math for integer problems.

```
// for (int i = 1; i <=sqrt(n); i++) { ... }
for (int i = 1; i <= n/i; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: Why not simplify the last test as `if (i * i == n) divisors += i;` ? Trying to keep defined behavior around `n = INT_MAX` ?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes.  Code `// look for perfect square if (i == n/i) {`  formed this way to avoid overflow of `i*i`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a program with reasonable performance. I omitted a few optimizations to keep it simple and educational.

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*  This is a program to find perfect numbers or "almost perfect" numbers.
    (The sum of the proper divisors of an almost perfect number n is n-1, so
    the sum of all the divisors is 2*n-1.  The "target" object can be set as
    desired to find numbers whose divisors sum to a specific total.)  It works
    by factoring candidates and computing the product of:

        1 + p + p^2 + … + p^e

    for each prime p, where e is the greatest integer such that p^e divides n.
    (Observe that, notionally, this product can be computed over every prime,
    all of the infinitely many primes, because, for any prime that does not
    divide n, e is 0, and then 1 + p + p^2 + … + p^e is just 1, and multiplying
    the product by 1 does not affect it.)

    Observe that each divisor of n is a product of some combination of the
    primes that divide n, each prime with some multiplicity.  Each of the 1 + p
    + p^2 + … + p^e factors in our product contains its prime p in each
    multiplicity from 0 to its e, inclusive.  When all of these factors are
    written as polynomials and multiplied, the terms of the expanded polynomial
    contain each combination of the primes that divide n with each combination
    of multiplicities.  Therefore, it is a list of all the divisors of n, and
    they are added together, so the polynomial equals the sum of the divisors
    of n (including 1 and n).  For example, with 72, 72 = 2^3 * 3^2, so our
    product is (1 + 2 + 4 + 8) * (1 + 3 + 9) = 1 + 3 + 9 + 2 + 6 + 18 + 4 + 12
    + 36 + 8 + 24 + 72 = 195, which is the sum of the divisors of 72.

    The program finds primes as it goes.

    Some things in it need to be verified, such as how far we can factor given
    the highest prime number we have remembered, especially as different
    control paths are taken.
*/


/*  Set a number of primes to remember.  This limits how far we can test as it
    limits our ability to factor numbers.
*/
#define AP  1000 // Number of elements Allocated for Primes.


int main(void)
{
    unsigned Primes[AP];
    unsigned NP = 0;    //  Number of filled elements in Primes.
    unsigned Limit = 4; //  Current limit on n we know we can support.

    /*  Test integers from 1 to Limit.  Limit will be increased as we find
        more primes.  It will stop increasing when our Primes array is full.
    */
    for (unsigned n = 1; n <= Limit; ++n)
    {
        //  Occasionally print a message to let user know of our progress.
        if (n % (1u<<22) == 0) printf("(Now at %u.)\n", n);
        
        /*  Set the target sum.  If it is 2*n, this program finds perfect
            numbers.  If it is 2*n-1, this program finds "almost perfect"
            numbers.
        */
        unsigned target = 2*n-1;

        /*  t is used as a temporary value as we factor n.  It starts at n and
            is divided by each prime factor found.

            Product records the product we are building.
        */
        unsigned t = n, Product = 1;

        /*  i indexes the Primes array and of course starts at 0.
            p is the current prime we are testing and starts at the first
            prime, 2.

            Once t is less than p*p, the loop stops, because then either t is
            1 or some prime number.  (Any composite number less than or equal
            to p*p has a factor less than or equal to p, so we would have found
            it and divided t by it.)
        */
        for (unsigned i = 0, p = 2; p*p <= t; p = Primes[++i])
        {
            //  Start the sum with p^0, which is 1.
            unsigned Sum = 1;

            /*  For each time p divides t, grow the Sum, forming 1+p+p^2+…p^e.
                For example, the Sum starts at 1.  If p divides t, then
                "Sum = 1 + Sum*p" sets it to 1+p.  If p divides t again, this
                sets it to 1+(1+p)*p = 1+p+p^2, and so on.
            */
            for (; t % p == 0; t /= p)
                Sum = 1 + Sum*p;

            //  Multiply the sum into the product.
            Product *= Sum;
        }

        //  If t has not been reduced to 1, it is the last prime factor of n.
        if (1 < t)
        {
            //  If there were no other factors, we have a new prime.
            if (Product == 1)
            {
                /*  If we still have space, remember the new prime and increase
                    Limit.  Knowing primes up to n lets us test numbers up to
                    n*n because any number up to n*n with a factor f larger
                    than n also has a factor smaller than n, namely that number
                    divided by f.
                */
                if (NP < AP)
                {
                    Primes[NP++] = n;
                    Limit = n*n;
                }
            }

            //  Multiply the series for the last factor into Product.
            Product *= 1+t;
        }

        //  If our criterion for n is met, report it.
        if (Product == target)
            printf("Found %u.\n", n);
    }
    printf("Tested numbers up to and including %u.\n", Limit);
}
```