# Counting of abundant numbers from 1 to N

Tags: c, optimization, number-theory

The problem is to count the abundant numbers from 1 to 10mil in about 10s gpu time but with the algorithms I have found so far the min time is 50s.Keep in mind that the limitation are not to use some sort of function that needs the mathematical library nor a dynamic or static data structure.Any suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXNUM 10000000

int main(void){
int counta=0,p,product;
 printf("Numbers abundant: ");
 for(unsigned n=1;n<=MAXNUM;++n){             
  unsigned temp=n;
  if( n % 2==0 || n % 3 ==0){
    product=1;
    for(p=2;p*p<=temp;p+=2){     
      unsigned sum=1;
      for(;temp % p==0;temp/=p){
       sum=1+sum*p;
       product*=sum;        
      }
     if(1>temp) {
      product*=1+temp;
     }
    }
   } 
    if(product>2*n) counta++;
  }   
 printf("%d\n",counta);
}
```

Comment: You've hit the secondary aim of the coding challenge: to find an efficient algorithm. Suggestions: 1) work with prime number divisors only, 2) break from the divisors loop once you have proved that the number is 'abundant'.

Comment: You can compute divisors much more quickly with the help of a table of primes.  You will need only the primes up to `sqrt(10000000)`, and you can pre-compute these at the start of the program, once, using a prime number sieve.  Compute the prime factorization of each number, and use that to build all the proper divisors.

Comment: You could further speed it with memoization of the sums of divisors of you've already calculated.

Comment: Isn't a table of primes a "dynamic or static data structure", @JohnBollinger?

Comment: Can you exploit the properties of [Abundant Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) listed on Wikipedia?

Comment: A requirement not to use a “dynamic or static data structure” is bizarre. Having a few related variables in your program is a rudimentary data structure. What is the actual wording of the requirement?

Comment: Why does the question mention “gpu time”? There is no apparent use of a GPU in the code.

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeffler, I would characterize it so.  I had overlooked that odd constraint.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if u compile and run the program in a linux terminal with the command time it shows how many seconds it took to run

Comment: Also i just started programming so the professor doesnt want us to use something we havent learned from him so yeah that is the contraint any data structures apart from simple variables

Comment: @Beasty: That is not GPU time. The `time` command shows elapsed time (real world time, also called wall clock time) and CPU time.

Comment: sorry i meant to write cpu time u are correct

Comment: @WeatherVane also how could I work with prime number divisors only?

Comment: I posted code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69891649/298225) two days ago that shows how to compute the sum of the divisors of a number without individually identifying all divisors. Adapting just that factoring-computation even without remembering the primes (no data structures) drops your program to 13 seconds. Then treating 2 separately and modifying the loop to test only odd numbers as divisors drops the time to 7 seconds.

Comment: thank you a lot for taking the time to help me so much but could u be more specific why I should only test odd numbers as divisors or is it explained in the code's comments? @EricPostpischil

Comment: @EricPostpischil i tried to do what u told me but i am too inexperienced and the program I made doesnt produce correct results could u help me out a bit?(the code is in the post)

Comment: You are on the right track, but your code needs some fixes. First, reduce the work to make it easier to monitor. Change `MAXNUM` to, say 30. And in the line `if (product > 2*n) counta++;`, change it to print the current value of `n` as well as incrementing count. Then you can see what numbers the program is deciding are abundant, which will help you catch errors. You could print `product` too, to see if it is correct.

Comment: Second, do not do anything fancy with factors 2 or 3 until you have the code working. Get rid of the tests for 2 and 3 and just use a plain loop that tests all numbers, `for (p = 2; p*p <= temp; ++p)`. Third, you need to correct which code goes inside which loops. For each number `n`, you are going to compute a product. That product consists of multiple terms, in which each term is computed as a sum for one prime factor. So there is an inner loop using `temp` that just computes `sum` for one factor `p`. After that loop, inside the loop for `p`, the computed `sum` is multiplied into `product`.

Comment: After the loop on `p`, if there is a leftover factor in `temp`, you want to multiply `1+temp` into `product`. But that is done only if `1 < temp`, not `1 > temp`.

Comment: Do some of the work by hand. Given the prime factorization of 12, 2^2•3^1, figure out what `sum` should be when `p` is 2 and what `sum` should be when `p` is 3 and what the product of those sums should be. Then check whether your code is computing those sums and that product for 12. Use a debugger or insert `printf` statements in your program to show what it is doing at various times.